# How to hide an element on an AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I've got a page that has a dropdown menu, and upon selection, creates a new element (a table) using an AJAX call. Firebug shows this on action:

> GET http://www.site.com/page.php?q=category

The actual code for this is:

```
select name="category" id="category" onchange="load(this.value)
```

However, in addition to it creating a new table, I'd like it to destroy/ not display another table that's already on the page. The table has *class="table2" id="PR"*. What additional code do I put into that select tag above? Thanks

Comment: Where is the rest of the code, i.e. for the `load` function?

Comment: You should format the question properly. Use the code tag for html and javascript sources - otherwise it won't appear correctly. Other users can't do that for you as they can only guess what you meant.

Comment: @Amokrane Chentir Even after clicking the accept tick, it doesn't register that I've done so.

Comment: @Simpleton: That is weird! May be you should ask a question about it on meta (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @Amokrane It seems that that was indeed the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
$('#PR').remove();
```

But maybe you'll need to make a function to call onchange:

```
function mychange(event)
{
  load( event.currentTarget.value );
  $('#PR').remove();
}

select name="category" id="category" onchange="mychange(event)"
```

Comment: `<select name="category" id="category" onchange="$('#PR').remove(); load(this.value)">` or inside the `load()` function

Answer (score 2):

I would change it so you have this code instead:

```
$(function() {
    $('#category').change(function() {
         load($(this).val());
         $('#PR').hide(); // or .remove() if you want to completely remove it;
    });
});
```

You can then remove the onchange from the select tag as it is wired up via the jquery event.

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery try:

```
onchange="load(this.value); document.getElementById('table1').style.display='none';"
```

Comment: Ew, don't put Javascript in HTML properties.

Comment: The question was "What additional code do I put into that select tag above?"