# How to hide a DIV that is produced by an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script that closes a DIV. An example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/22fTm/3/

My problem however, is that the DIV "box" is only produced after an ajax call, which is part of a search php script.

Any idea what I need to make this work? Similar question: [How to hide an element on an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116200/how-to-hide-an-element-on-an-ajax-call)

Comment: #searchresultdata {display:none} :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the element is created dynamically you have to use `on` or `delegate` which take care of triggering the event even when the elements are added dynamically.

Using `on`

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "div.box a.close", function() {
        $(this).parent("div.box").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

`on()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/ JQuery ver 1.7+

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/22fTm/4/)**

Using `delegate`

```
$(function(){
    $(document).delegate("div.box a.close", "click", function() {
        $(this).parent("div.box").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

`delegate()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/22fTm/7/)**

Comment: Using delegate worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

.live will help :)
http://api.jquery.com/live/

But you could also display the div by default and set it to display:none and then toggle the div a soon as some one does a search...

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7

Answer (score 1):

When you dynamically insert elements with AJAX any handlers registered with the original `.bind()` or `.click()` methods won't work, because they only work on elements that are already in the DOM at the time.

You need to either:

1. re-register the handler after the content has been added to the DOM, or
2. use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (if you're using jQuery 1.7+) to register a "live" handler which will work even on elements that are created after the handler was registered.

e.g.:

```
$(document).on('click', '.search-sbox .close', function() {
    ....
});
```

if using jQuery prior to 1.7, use `.live()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try changing it into

```
$(function(){
    $("div.box a.close").live("click", function() {
        $(this).parent("div.box").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is for supporting event-handlers, also after the dom is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

That usually depends on When do you want it to hide?

for example you may use

```
$('.select').live('click',function (){
    $('div').hide();
});
```

you may also use **delegate**,

also, you can use it on ajax success, if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Below Javascript should work, it uses jquery's delegate function, as live is deprecated in jquery

```
$("#searchresultdata").delegate("a.close", "click", function() {
    $(this).closest("div.box").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delagate events. In your case use this code for your site:

```
$('#searchresultdata').delegate('div.search-sbox a.close', 'click', function() {
    $(this).parent("div.search-sbox").fadeOut();
});
```